# Software recommendation for a setup that requires fast atomic batch incrementations and fast batch reads of those counters

Tags: java, software-development, database

### Context:

- This is a `Jersey` application
- Run on a `Tomcat` server
- Connects to a `MySQL` database using `Hibernate`
- All on `Netbeans`

I have an application that has `Item` objects. Each `Item` has a unique `Number` id and as many as 100 metrics associated with it. Each metric has it's own unique `Number` id and a single field associated with it, a counter. I'm looking for a software recommendation that would be conducive to two things:

- very frequent, large, batch, atomic incrementations of an `Item`'s metrics given a list of `Number`'s representing the metric ids.
- very frequent, large, batch reads of all an `Item`'s metrics

Ideally, the read would result in a `Map<Number,Number>` where an individual `Map` corresponds to an item, the keys are the metric ids, and the values are the metrics' corresponding counters.

I've come up with a couple implementations myself, but they don't seem well suited for both tasks.

**Implementation 1:**

A MySQL table exists in the form:

```
CREATE TABLE `metric` (
 `item_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `metric_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `counter` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 PRIMARY KEY (`item_id`,`metric_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

I create a `Metric` `Hibernate` entity and add a `HashMap<Number,Metric>` field to the `Item` entity. This means everything would be done in MySQL. Reads would be performed by using the `Item`'s id -- fast. Incrementations would be done probably with a SQL statement like so:

```
UPDATE metric SET counter=counter+1 WHERE item_id=<Item's id>
AND metric_id=<List of metric ids>
```

*the list of metric ids would never consist of all of an `Item`'s metrics

I would love to use this implemenation. It just doesn't seem like MySQL is well suited for the task of frequent, large batch incrementations of counters. Please correct me if I am wrong.

**Implementation 2:**

Uses `Redis` -- really want to avoid implementing an in-memory solution if I can.

This uses `Redis` `Hashes` to store a particular `Item`'s metrics. A `Hash` would be referenced with an `Item`'s id and the counter fields would be referenced using the corresponding metric id.

The data structure seems well suited for the task. A slight performance slip would be that `Redis` doesn't seem to natively support batch incrementations for `Hash`'s. So every time a counter field is incremented the `Hash` needs to be searched for again.

The biggest issue with this implementation is that Redis stores all values in Strings. And the seemingly most popular `Java` client only retrieves `Hash`'s as `Map<String,String>`. Which means I would have to, at the least, convert each value to an Integer (potentially 100) -- like I said, Ideally I end up with a `Map<Number,Number>` after reads.

Anyone have any thoughts on what technology would be well suited for this use case?

### Update:

It seems like `Reddison` another `Java` client for `Redis`, uses generics to create `ReddisonMap`'s that represent `Hash`'s. I'm not sure how it does the conversion from `Hash` to `ReddisonMap`, but it seems like I can get a `Map<Number,Number>` using it -- but as I said, I'd like to avoid using an in-memory solution if I can.

Comment: An in-memory solution that converted strings to numbers, added one, converted back to strings is likely to be a lot faster than an implementation that logically has to touch the disk on each record operation.  If you really hate the Redis implementation, you can always modify it or roll your own.

Comment: @IraBaxter that's why i'm looking for a solution that would enable me to perform batch updates on the disk. wouldn't this prevent me from the overhead of going back and forth? also, the reason i don't want to use `Redis` is because the amount of ram i have at my disposal is limited.

Comment: RAM is dirt cheap, and if that solves your problem, it is the fastest and easiest way.  So what's the objection?